# Set a default value for a dynamically created asp.net DropDownList that is already populated

Tags: c#, asp.net

Fairly new to .NET and C# so please excuse my ignorance.

I have an Update/Edit Web-Form that is used to allow students to ***edit*** changes to their class choices for a given seminar. Since the seminars can be 2 to 5 days long and each seminar can have 1 to 12 classes, out of 120 classes, I have to dynamically  create the DropDownLists with a placeholder. I can populate the DDLs easy enough but I need to have the student’s prior selections be the default value when the students open the “Edit Web-Form.” My question is what is the cleanest way to achieve this? And, is there a way to create the DDLs then go back and set the default values after the DDLs are created, maybe by looping through the form elements in the C# code behind?

Comment: first, fill the dropdownlists, then given the students prior selection foreach dropdownlist use `ddl.Items.FindByText` or `ddl.Items.FindByValue` with `ddl.Items.IndexOf` and set `ddl.SelectedIndex`

Comment: Thanks. One more dumb question, when I do a foreach loop what should I use to loop through the form elements? something like foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)? The number and IDs of the DDLs will be different depending on the seminar.

Comment: you probably need to use some naming scheme for same type of DDL and use some kind of for or while loop which will break when it will not find an element in specific naming scheme. For finding proper control use `Page.FindControl` but be carefull because it searches only in top level: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ie: ddlSeminar1, ddlSeminar2 etc

Comment: your solution of course depends on how do you create your controls, Read about dynamicallyy created control and viewstate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hbdfdyh7.aspx

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks so much for the response and information. IOU!

Comment: Forgot to post the answer I came up with after tinamou pointed me in the right direction. As tinamou said, I populated the dynamically created dropdownlists. The DDLs are named via a database value stored in a user's registration. I then I created a for statement to loop through the database values and assigned the values using:  

strClassID = dtModReg.Rows[x][0].ToString();
strControlID = dtModReg.Rows[x][1].ToString();
DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)FindControl(strControlID);
ddl1.SelectedValue = strClassID;